# preg_match to show first image from other php/html file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show my new Blog entries automatically on a site. So i found a little php script and modified it to my needs:

`if (preg_match("/<img src=(.*jpg$)>/i", $data, $titleb)) { $bild = $titleb[1]; }`

I want this script to basically show on my Site the newest headline, a small exerpt and to show the latest image.
The Headlines work perfectly but I cannot get anything for the image. How can I fix this? Thank you all for your help. Please don't be too hash on me - I am just a beginner.

(I am sorry I did not post the whole script as I could not get StackOverflow to accept it as properly formatted)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$html = "<html><body><a href='post.html'><img src='img.jpg'>View post</a> <a href='post2.html'><img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg'>View post 2</a> <a href='post2.html'><img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png'>View post 3</a></body></html>";

echo $html . "\n preg: ";

# get all img-tags
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $result);
$img = array();
foreach( $result[0] as $k => $img_tag){
    echo 'img_tag: ';
    print_r($img_tag);
    echo "\n";
    preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src="?\'?([^"\']+)"?\'?[^>]*>/i', $img_tag, $img[$k], PREG_SET_ORDER);
}

# show image urls
foreach ($img as $image) {
    echo $image[0][1] . "\n"; # image URLs
}
```

*Example output:*

```
<html><body><a href='post.html'><img src='img.jpg'>View post</a> <a href='post2.html'><img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg'>View post 2</a> <a href='post2.html'><img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png'>View post 3</a></body></html>
 preg: img_tag: <img src='img.jpg'>
img_tag: <img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg'>
img_tag: <img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png'>
img.jpg
http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg
http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png
```

*Variable $img contents:*

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(19) "<img src='img.jpg'>"
      [1] =>
      string(7) "img.jpg"
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(47) "<img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg'>"
      [1] =>
      string(35) "http://www.yandex.ru/image/img2.jpg"
    }
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(47) "<img src='http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png'>"
      [1] =>
      string(35) "http://www.yandex.ru/image/img3.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this (the only thing i needed was the
'/<img[^>]+src="?\'?([^"\']+)"?\'?[^>]*>/i' part - now it works perfectly.